# Extension struct imported from C

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I'm novice to Swift and I have this extension:

```
extension UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions {
    init(animationOptions: UIView.AnimationOptions) {
        rawValue = animationOptions.rawValue
    }
}
```

Since Swift 4.2  the `rawValue = animationOptions.rawValue` produces this warning:

```
Initializer for struct 'UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions' must use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." because the struct was imported from C
```

I use the extension like that:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(animationOptions: .curveEaseOut)], animations: {
...
}
```

How can I fix this warning message from a `struct was imported from C`?

Comment: Why would you attempt to create a `UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions` from a value of type `UIView.AnimationOptions`? That's not appropriate. They are different types with different uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was never correct. It should be:

```
extension UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions {
    init(animationOptions: UIView.AnimationOptions) {
        self.init(rawValue: animationOptions.rawValue)
    }
}
```

But, this is a bad idea. You are forcing the options of one enumeration into an unrelated enumeration. This is going to cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of that is to restrict cross-module struct initializers. And that enforces the safety of initializing a struct.

> Swift structs are designed to be flexible and their implementation
>   could be changed between releases. Since initializers have to
>   initialize *every* stored property, they have two options:
>
> - Assign each property before returning or using self.
> - Assign all properties at once by using `self.init(…)` or `self = …`.
>
> The former requires knowing *every* stored property in the struct. If
>   all of those properties happen to be public, however, a client in
>   another target can implement their own initializer, and suddenly
>   adding a new stored property (public or not) becomes a source-breaking
>   change.

You can find more details here [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0189-restrict-cross-module-struct-initializers.md).

Your code, as of **Swift 4.1**, should look like this:

```
extension UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions {
    init(animationOptions: UIView.AnimationOptions) {
        self = .init(rawValue: animationOptions.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Two answers code work well.